# how to get data from min - max joining two columns from same table

Tags: sql, max, min

```
select s1.name,min(s1.start_time),max(s2.end_time),
round(((max(s2.end_time) - min(s1.start_time)))*24)
from My_table s1,My_table s2
where (s1.process in ('abcd') and month like '%1708021%') and 
(s2.process in ('xyz' and month like '%1708021%'))
group by s1.process_name;

PROCESS_NAME    MIN(S1.START_TIME)  MAX(S2.END_TIME)    ROUND(((MAX(S2.END_TIME)-MIN(S1.START_TIME))))
alert17 18-aug-2021 07:49:45 PM 20-aug-2021 12:01:09 PM 40
```

i have 31 entries in my table if i run above query i get correct data from it i.e. process start_time and end_time as well as difference.

but if i run it on month level then it gives me wrong data

```
select s1.name,min(s1.start_time),max(s2.end_time),
round(((max(s2.end_time) - min(s1.start_time)))*24)
from My_table s1,My_table s2
where (s1.process in ('abcd') and month like '%08021%') and 
(s2.process in ('xyz' and month like '%08021%'))
group by s1.process_name;

Alert01 03-aug-2021 01:50:47 AM 27-aug-2021 06:16:30 AM 580
Alert02 03-aug-2021 08:10:57 PM 27-aug-2021 06:16:30 AM 562
Alert03 04-aug-2021 08:07:21 PM 27-aug-2021 06:16:30 AM 538
Alert04 06-aug-2021 03:42:51 AM 27-aug-2021 06:16:30 AM 507
```

can you guys help me ?

Comment: It is difficult to decipher what you are attempting to do.  It would seem like it would be clearer and much more efficient to eliminate the join and replace it with filtering in the aggregate function.  You are grouping by only one column, so I might guess the join is not what you want anyway.

Comment: @RohanDolas . . . My advice:  Delete this question.  Ask a new question.  Provide a *clear* explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.  Provide sample data and desired results.  And then show the query(ies) that work or do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a likely error in your logic.  Notice the difference between this:

```
and (s2.process in ('xyz'   and month like '%1708021%'))
```

and this:

```
and (s2.process in ('xyz')   and month like '%1708021%')
```

The second form is likely what you wanted to do.

I suspect this impacts both the query you think produces correct results and the other query you thought had the only problem.

Also, be careful of the following.

You have selected `name`, but have grouped by `process_name`.  It's possible this is a functional dependence issue, which would be considered invalid in terms of standard SQL.

Some databases ignore this kind of mistake (if it's really a FD mistake).  It's tough to tell without the full detail.